# Microsd card can't be mounted; none of previous solutions worked! Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mount, sd-card, micro-sd

I have a sand disk microsd card (Extreme  Extreme microSDHC 3), it is brand new. Unfortunately, I can not mount it. I tried several solutions suggested but it does not seem to solve the issue. I will bring here the steps that I took:
1) sudo fdisk -l 
[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqXQz.png)

2) sudo mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk0 /mnt/SD/ gave me the following output:

mount: /mnt/SD: can't read superblock on /dev/mmcblk0

3) I checked that if the exfat utilities are installed. It seems that they are up-to-date.

4) I tried sudo parted -l /dev/mmcblk0, and the output is the following:

Error: /dev/mmcblk0: unrecognised disk label
Model: SD SM32G (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 31,9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:

5) using disk utilities, I faced the following error:

[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6stV.png)

6) Gparted gave me the following error, when I started it!

[gparted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeGqo.png)

I would be really grateful if someone could help me to figure out this problem.
Bests,
Muh

Comment: Are there a rw/ro switch on the microsd card? And is it at rw ? Also check the last lines in /var/log/dmesg just after inserting the microsd card, for relevant information.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I tested the rw/ro switch, it will not help, since the problem is mounting, not dealing with the content. Unfortunately, there is no  /var/log/dmesg on my system.

Comment: It looks like that there are no label or partition table on the card. Ubuntu has to label and format it first. That what some of the messages / errors you get tells. Since the card, for some reason, registers as read-only, this is not possible. If you can't find /var/log/dmesg, you can run the command `dmesg` from terminal.  Have you checked if the card is broken ?

Comment: I don't think the card is broken, since I inserted it on an android phone for a test, and it could store photos and videos on it. dmesg results in : [ 3841.585597] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card